# Turn a Text File into a String at Compile Time

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a text file with some C-like plain text. I would like to, at compile time (and ideally using `cmake`), take the text in this file and use it to generate a simple C++ header file - one that has a couple of includes, namespace declaration, and an std::string whose value is the contents of my text file, new lines and everything included.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: A simple shell script should be able to do it. Read the file and then write it into the initialization of `std::string varname = "...";`. The main thing to remember is to escape any double quotes and backslashes.

Comment: @Barmar: Probably easier to use a raw string literal (at least in most cases).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. The easiest way is to use some nested `#include` statement inside a raw string literal definition.

Comment: If the main goal is to get the file contents into a string literal, you might appreciate the work going on for a [file string literals proposal](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/tKioR8OUiAw).

Comment: Raw string literals looks very much what I would love to use if I wasn't stuck on C++ 98... =\

Comment: What do you actually need? Why compile-time? Isn't config.h not enough?

Comment: @usr1234567 The compiled version needs to serve as a default. So I compose the text file once, then use a copy of it in source (automatically), but if I need to test with a different file, I can just provide it as an override to the default and avoid recompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I went with a solution different from the ones suggested here. Here's what I did.

Inside my source code, I define a handler class where I will make use of the string literal I need. Two things are important here:

- The header file is actually an `.hpp.in` while under version control. The implementation file is a normal `.cpp`
- Inside this header file, I choose a variable and #define it so: `#define MY_STRING @MY_STRING@`

Now, inside the CMakeLists.txt responsible for these two files, I do this:

- Read the raw text file into a cmake variable
- Remove all `//` comments, save the result in a temporary variable
- Replace all `\n` characters with the string `"newline"`, save the result into a new temporary variable
- Define the same variable I used in my header above above (i.e. `MY_STRING`), and assign it from that latest temporary variable
- Copy the header from the its location under ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} into the appropriate location under ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} (and renaming it to a `.hpp`) by specifying `@ONLY`. This ensures that cmake will copy the header file, but will also update the `#define MY_STRING @MY_STRING@` with the value of `MY_STRING` I set a little earlier.

Finally, inside the implementation file for my handler I define the following macros:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
```

so that I can call `TOSTRING(MY_STRING)` and assign the output to an `std::string my_string`. Once this is done, all I need to do is replace the `"newline"` placeholder strings with `"\n"` - and I am done! `my_string` now has a value equivalent to the the one in the raw text file (sans the comments there).

I wish I had more time to play with this, and fewer other tasks to distract me, but the way things are, this will have to do for now.

Thank you all for you help!