# Is there a way to pull in a text resource into a raw string literal using the pre-processor?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, string-literals

I've just noticed that an answer I have given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487971/turn-a-text-file-into-a-string-at-compile-time) actually doesn't work:

> > Regardless of using CMake or not, the following should work with the current standard:
> >
> > ```
> > std::string resource = R"(
> > #include "text.txt"
> > )";
> > ```

I thought that the pre-processor would recognize the `#include "text.txt"` statement in first place and expand the text.

But that's obviously not the case, the result for

```
std::cout << resource << std::endl;
```

is

> ```
> #include "text.txt"
> ```

I tried to use some macro to let the `#include` statement be expanded within, but it doesn't work either:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define RESOURCE_DEFINIION(resource_var,resource_name) \
    const std::string resource_var = R"xxx( \
    #include resource_name \
    )xxx";

RESOURCE_DEFINIION(resource,"text.txt")

int main()
{
   std::cout << resource << std::endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

The output is

> ```
> \                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     #include resource_name \
> ```

[Here's the demo to play with](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRktld3FXRnpSRzA)

---

Is there any trickery available to pull in the `text.txt` resource into a c++-11 raw-string literal, using the pre-processor or any other regular c++ language feature?

---

**Disclaimer:**

I well know what's wrong with the above samples and why these fail this way. It's a problem that the pre-processor ignores the stuff appearing within `"` pairs.

So is there a way to escape these to be seen by the pre-processor?

Comment: Do you want to assign the text to a variable or do you want the text as a preprocessor directive?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The text should be accessible from a variable as shown in the sample. It should be used to initialize the `resource` string.

Comment: Nope, not without modifying `text.txt`. That's why there's this discussion and proposal: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-proposals/tKioR8OUiAw

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. You can't `#include` the contents in a string variable.

Comment: I don't think there's a way with the preprocessor.  You can use other tools to do it, though.  `xxd -i` can do this for you.  I've used it before to embed a resource file in a binary.

Comment: that's why I made [ris](https://github.com/d-led/ris) - to make this task bearable and as hassle-free as possible

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Interesting stuff THX. But I actually only wanted to know if that is somehow possible at all. The accepted answer is perfectly fine. I'd use simpler tools like sed or so to preprocess text files.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the answer. I see your point! Indeed, it would be great, if it were possible via the language itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like not possible in standard C++

**Problem 0**: Only standard way of textual inclusion is `#include` directive.

**Problem 1**: String literal is a preprocessing token, which are recognised in phase 3, so when preprocessing directives are executed in phase 4, it is already determined that `#include` is a part of string literal and not a preprocessing directive.

> *preprocessing-token:
>
>       header-name
>
>       identifier
>
>       pp-number
>
>       character-literal
>
>       user-defined-character-literal
>
>       string-literal
>
>       user-defined-string-literal
>
>       preprocessing-op-or-punc
>
>       each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above*

**Problem 2**: It is impossible to bring preprocessing directive in source and execute it by macro substitution:

> **16.3.4/3**
>   The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one

So you cannot have working `#include` inside macro.

**Problem 3**: macro replacement list should be a valid preprocessing token:

> *control-line:*
>       *# define identifier replacement-list new-line*
>   *replacement-list:*
>           *pp-tokens opt*
>   *pp-tokens:*
>       *preprocessing-token*
>       *pp-tokens preprocessing-token*

And string literal  is a preprocessing token itself, you cannot build string literal from several macro.