# How to include character literals?

Tags: c++, special-characters

I have a question on how to include string literals when getting info from a file. Let me show my code for better understanding:

**Program.b**:

```
print \"Hello World\n\"; print \"Commo Estas :)\n\"; print \"Bonjour\";print \"Something\"; return 0;
```

**main.cpp** (I have minimized the actual file to what is needed for this question):

```
int main()
{
    std::string file_contents;
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("Program.b");
    std::ifstream file_read;
    file_read.open("Program.b");

    if(file_read.is_open())
        while(getline(file_read,file_contents));

    cout << file_contents << endl;

}
```

So right now when I print `file_contents`, I get:

```
print \"Hello World\n\"; print \"Commo Estas :)\n\"; print \"Bonjour\";print \"Something\"; return 0;
```

You can see it includes the `\n` . Is there a way to make that an actual character literal, so printing it actually prints a new line? (I would want the same for quotation marks.)

Comment: Do you need to read the file at runtime? Otherwise you could probably make use of the preprocessor.

Comment: No i dont need to , @πάνταῥεῖ . What do you mean i can make use of a preprocessor? .. `#define toStr(x) #x` ?

Comment: Here is a link which does what you want: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612182/convert-string-with-explicit-escape-sequence-into-relative-character)

Comment: @amanuel2 You may adjust your `Program.b` a bit, and use a `#include "Program.b"` statement to initialize a `std::string` variable for example.

Comment: @Rikocar .. hmm the `unescape(file_contents);` , doesn't work using the `unescape` function from that particular answer that got accepted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Program.b is not a C++ File , just saying , just a BoneLang File :P . and what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @Rikocar oh seems to work when i just print out the return statement `cout << unescape(file_contents) << endl;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

**Program.b**

```
R"inp(print "Hello World\n"; print "Commo Estas :)\n"; print "Bonjour";print "Something"; return 0;)inp"
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    std::string file contents = 
    #include "Program.b"
    ;
    std::cout << file_contents << std::endl;

}
```

---

You can also change `Program.b` to make it a bit more readable:

```
R"inp(
print "Hello World\n"; 
print "Commo Estas :)\n"; 
print "Bonjour";
print "Something"; 
return 0;
)inp"
```

---

The runtime variant should be simply:

**Program.b**

```
print "Hello World\n"; 
print "Commo Estas :)\n"; 
print "Bonjour";
print "Something"; 
return 0;
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    std::string file_contents;
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("Program.b");
    std::ifstream file_read;
    file_read.open("Program.b");

    if(file_read.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while(getline(file_read,line)) {
             file_contents += line + `\n`;
        }
    }

    cout << file_contents << endl;

}
```

Comment: Wow, that is hacky though :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 hmm limits BoneLang Capability. because i have to use R . I got another way though that doesn't require `R`. Thanks this will be helpfull to readers

Comment: @amanuel2 _"because i have to use R_ Well, unfortunately you can't put that outside of the `Program.b` file, since `#include` doesn't work within double quotes. I was asking something similar here, give me a minute.

Comment: @amanuel2 Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622767/is-there-a-way-to-pull-in-a-text-resource-into-a-raw-string-literal-using-the-pr

Comment: That seems a "hackish" way :P . See [**this**](https://gist.github.com/amanuel2/b8d02b026715e54857313066c799316d) gist . gotta go next period chaw!\

Comment: @amanuel2 Extended my answer, based on looking to your gist. Seems the more appropriate way for that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple find + replace.

```
std::size_t pos = std::string::npos;
while ((pos = file_contents.find("\\n")) != std::string::npos)
    file_contents.replace(pos, 1, "\n");

//Every \n will have been replaced by actual newline character
```

Comment: Wow seems like a good idea but that will be kinda tedious when you need more. Should i post my solution to?

Comment: @amanuel2 You can always make a generic function that will remove any special characters with their actual representation.

Comment: Thanks. See [**this**](https://gist.github.com/amanuel2/b8d02b026715e54857313066c799316d) gist . gotta go next period chaw!